# Html.Dropdownlist selected value is not posted back to the Controller from view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-select

I am trying to have a dropdownlist on Create.chtml where a user can select a 'NAME' from the dropdownlist and the corresponding value (ID) should be sent back to controller to add it to the database table.

**What is working:** I can see the dropdownlist with NAMES on the Create.chtml view page

**What is NOT working:** when a NAME is selected from the dropdownlist in the view, its value (ID) is not passed to Controller

Please see the code below to identify where I might be doing it wrong.

```
Controller:

//
        // GET: /OrganizationCodes/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            var orgzList = (from x in db.TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS
                                                   select new TABLE_ORGANIZATIONSDTO
                                                   {
                                                       ID = x.ID,
                                                       NAME = x.NAME
                                                   }).OrderBy(w => w.NAME).ToList();

            ViewBag.orgz = new SelectList(orgzList, "ID", "NAME");

            return View();
        }

        public class TABLE_ORGANIZATIONSDTO
        {
            public string NAME { get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }
        }

        //
        // POST: /OrganizationCodes/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TABLE_CODES dp)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new IngestEntities())
                {


                    TABLE_CODES codes_temp = new TABLE_CODES();
                    ViewBag.orgz = codes_temp;

                    db.AddToTABLE_CODES(dp);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

===================================================================================
View: 'Create.chtml'

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

         <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("orgz", (SelectList)ViewBag.orgz)
        </div>      

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

   </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Edit 1:

[image]

Edit 2:

I am trying to have a view with a dropdownlist of NAMES with value as ID from table 'TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS' which should be added to table 'TABLE_CODES' -> 'MANAGER' column as a number

Comment: This question can't be answered until you specify what the `TABLE_CODES` object looks like.  When you POST data to the controller the framework is going to try and model bind your inputs into the object type.

Comment: I am trying to have a view with a dropdownlist of NAMES with value as ID from table 'TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS' which should be added to table 'TABLE_CODES' -> 'MANAGER' column as a number

Comment: @Matt Houser already answered your question. Either change the DropDownList name `@Html.DropDownList("dp", (SelectList)ViewBag.orgz)` or action parameter name `ActionResult Create(TABLE_CODES orgz)`.

Comment: @archer, that's not how model binding works.

Comment: @MattHouser I am using ViewBag

Comment: `ViewBag` won't help you here. `ViewBag` is simply a general-purpose storage of data from controller to view.  It does nothing, and is empty, during the post-back.

Comment: @MattHouser: when I used @Html.DropDownList("dp.MANAGER", (SelectList)ViewBag.orgs) - data is sent to controller somehow I don't understand how - is it may be Html.DropDownlist helper is helping with it

Comment: @MattHouser please let me know what you think from my above comment.

Comment: It's because your `<select>` will look like `<select id="dp.MANAGER" name="dp.MANAGER">...</select>`.  MVC model binding will bind that to the `MANAGER` property of your `dp` parameter on your action.  It does this because the **name matches**:  `dp.MANAGER` -> `dp.MANAGER`.

Comment: @MattHouser Thanks for the explanation! So, how do you see my approach? Is it not advisable to do it the way I did?

Comment: If that is where you want the variable to go on the post-back, then yes that is what you should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your action `Create`, `[HttpPost]` version, in which variable are you expecting to see the value of your selected name?

You've named your `<select>` element with id = "orgz", but you don't have a parameter to your action method named "orgz".

**Edit:**

When you do:

```
@Html.DropDownList("orgz", (SelectList)ViewBag.orgz)
```

You're going to end up with HTML like this:

```
<select id="orgz" name="orgz">...</select>
```

When the form is posted back to the controller action, it will try to find a variable called "orgz" that it will put the selected item from your `<select>` element into.  You are missing this.

Try changing your `[HttpPost]` version of `Create` to include an "orgz" variable:

```
public ActionResult Create(TABLE_CODES dp, int orgz)
{
  // orgz will contain the ID of the selected item
}
```

Then your variable "orgz" will contain the ID of the selected item from your drop down list.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("orgz", (SelectList)ViewBag.orgz)`, the first parameter is the name of the form field to return, not id of the element. Id of the `select` will be the same in this case, but it has nothing to do with binding form values to an action parameters.